# Hawtio not recognizing Jboss EAP

Tags: jboss, hawtio

I have downloaded latest hawtio and deployed in my Jboss EAP 6.2 
I followed the instructions [here](http://www.christianposta.com/blog/?p=409) to make the hawtio war compatible with jboss eap.
However, I found that hawtio web app was up but was not showing local jboss server mbeans on which it was deployed.
Can you please point out what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at wildfly-camel module that ships with hawtio supported out of the box. This module is intended of EAP / wildfly containers

- https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel
- http://wildflyext.gitbooks.io/wildfly-camel/content/features/hawtio.html